# How to add and subtract the matrix index values in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Let's say I have a 3x3 matrix. In a function, I want to define two variables m , n as index numbers of the matrix dimensions.

I want to subtract all possible combinations. How would I define that in a function?

I.e.: (m-n) should do = (1-1), (1-2), (1-3), (2-1), (2-2), (2-3), (3-1), (3,2), (3,3). Not the matrix cell values, just index values (1,2,3).

df_matrix is multi index pandas dataframe.

```
df_matrix 

m   1   2   3
n
1   x   y   z
2   a   b   c 
3   p   q   r
```

Comment: what's the desired output?*

Comment: I want to do:  (m-n)^2 * c(m,n) => multiply the square of the difference in index values by the cell value. I'll use this function in a time series, create the matrix in 30 minute bins and do this operation for every 30 minute boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, without loops, you can do (M is your m x n matrix):

```
m = np.arange(M.shape[0]) #List of indexes of the first dimension (lines) 
m = m.reshape((M.shape[0], 1)) #transpose to obtain a vertical matrix 
n=np.arange(M.shape[1]) #List of indexes of second dimensions (columns)  
S = np.sum(M * (m-n)**2) #Compute the sum
```

*** First answer below, not as pretty in my opinion... ***

Not sure to understand the question clearly, but here is an attempt:

You can make a nested loop for all possible values of m and n

```
# Loop over all indexes of the first dimension
for m in range(df_matrix.shape[0]):
# Loop over all indexes of the second dimension
    for n in range(df_matrix.shape[1]):
        # Do whatever you want with indexes
        diff = m - n
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. How would you do the following operation in this function:  sum ((m-n)^2 * c(m,n))==> I.e. square of the difference between index values, multiplied by the values of the corresponding cell and summation of all of it?

Comment: So, (1-1)^2*x + (1-2)^2*y + (1-3)^2 *z + ...

Comment: before the first loop, initialize a sum variable:
`sum = 0`
Then inside the double loop, replace the line with diff=... with `sum += (m-n)**2 * fd_matrix[m, n]`
This will add your formula to the `sum` variable.

Comment: I edited my answer with a simpler way that does not use loops and harvest all the power of numpy arrays